# How do I change what each of the fn keys do?

Tags: keyboard

How do I change how my function keys work? On my one computer, the f1 and f2 keys change the volume. When I go to my second computer, they are at f11 and f12. I always seem to accidentally hit f1 and f2 on my second computer,and since I use my first computer much more frequently I need a way to set the f1 and f2 keys on my second computer to also be volume

Note: Third party software is fine with me. I have already tried using SharpKeys, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will let you remap any key or mouse button.  It can map the function keys to raise or lower the volume, as well as just about anything.

Comment: Okay, I will look at that. I already have AutoHotkey, but I had no idea it could remap keys.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked, except for the fact that I am used to pressing the fn key also. To get this to work for me, I have to disable to fn key somehow. Do you know if I could do that too? The fn key on my computer normally either puts my computer to sleep or puts it into airplane mode.